# SQL Query with date range Male Female

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that works but I need to incorporate in that query the following:

For male date is older or equals 3 months;
For female date is older or equals 4 months;

```
SELECT * 
FROM Davaoci
WHERE DatumPoslednjegDavanja >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
  AND KrvnaGrupa = 'APos' 
ORDER BY DatumPoslednjegDavanja DESC
```

Comment: How do you identify gender?  What column is used for "older"?

Comment: Gender column is Pol (M,F). DatumPoslednjegDavanja is of "older"

Comment: The query above is for male. But how do I add IF female than DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE())

Comment: Replace `DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())` with `CASE WHEN POL = 'M' THEN DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) ELSE DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE()) END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Davaoci
WHERE DatumPoslednjegDavanja >= DATEADD(
  month, 
  CASE WHEN Pol = 'M' THEN -3 ELSE -4 END, 
  GETDATE()
)
AND KrvnaGrupa = 'APos' 
ORDER BY DatumPoslednjegDavanja DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Based off your comments on the question, I made some adjustments to my answer. Working through our language barrier, I *think* this is what you're looking for.

NOTE: The way I have this set up now, it will only accept rows where the `Pol` column has an 'M' or 'F'. You may need to adjust the `ELSE` as needed.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Davaoci
WHERE
    KrvnaGrupa = 'APos'
    AND CASE
        WHEN Pol = 'M'
        THEN DatumPoslednjegDavanja >= DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())
        WHEN Pol = 'F'
        THEN DatumPoslednjegDavanja <= DATEADD(month, -4, GETDATE())
        ELSE FALSE
        END
ORDER BY
    DatumPoslednjegDavanja DESC;
```